# Books on induction complementary to Spivak's Calculus

Tags: reference-request, induction

I'm going through Spivak's Calculus, and I find that questions in chapter 2 are disproportionate in difficulty to the information provided in that chapter. 
Solution to the very first problem relying on induction:

> Prove that $\binom{n}{k}$ is always a natural number

contains steps that are not outlined, and can't be easily deduced from studying the book alone. Hence my question: can someone point me in a direction of a self-sufficient book on Induction, or at least one that contains enough information for me to be able to get back to Spivak shortly?

Comment: Ch.3 of Tamara Lakins, ,[The Tools of Mathematical Reasoning](https://books.google.it/books?id=pwkDDQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), American Mathematical Society (2016).

Comment: Randall Holmes, [Introduction to Advanced Mathematics](https://web.auburn.edu/holmerr/3100/Textbook/IntroAdvMath.pdf) (2017)